# Quick way to summarise container status within a multi-container pod

Tags: kubernetes

If I have several containers in a pod, and 2/3 are OK, is there a nice way to obtain a summary of which are OK and which are not?

Comment: you can use `kubectl get pod <pod-name>-o jsonpath='{range .status.containerStatuses[*]}{.name} {.image} {.ready}{"\n"}'`, for just the output.

Comment: OR `kubectl get pod foo -o jsonpath='{range .status.containerStatuses[*]}{.name} {.image} {.state}{"\n"}'` for  output with cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of info I usually filter out the output from describe command:

```
kubectl describe pod myFailingPod | grep -E "(Image:|State:)"
```